# Is cat food safe for human consumption?

Tags: food-safety

*Completely genuine question*

### Background

I was just feeding my cat, I was giving her some cat food that had 'duck' on the front and I remembered that I had some of that duck meat when I went to a restaurant and thought it was nice. The cat food looked really tasty so I decided to get out a tablespoon.

My cat was obviously quite disappointed that I had put a spoonful of her cat food into my mouth. I only took one spoonful. I didn't think it was that bad.

### Question

Am I going to get really ill?
Can I eat cat food again?

Please don't judge me...

Comment: @Max but that question is closed, so it doesn't really matter that it's a cross-site duplicate. :)

Comment: Was this wet food? In a can/pouch? Did it require refrigeration before opening?

Comment: Wet food, a pouch, no refrigeration. I just took it out of a cardboard box. @Catija

Comment: Don't ever serve it to someone else unaware of the fact, and you won't be judged :)

Comment: Who downvoted it? Given that there are certainly quality standards for pet food, their transferability to human food safety is a perfectly valid question. And I assume most parasites or microbes that would make a human sick would make a cat sick. And I could think of more ingredients that would make a cat sick but no human than the other way around.

Comment: Some people taste pet food for a living http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-514630/Pedigrees-chum-Meet-man-M-S-tests-pets-ready-meals.html

Comment: @rackandboneman it's irrelevant who downvoted it. I don't necessarily agree with it but it doesn't really matter. Perhaps they don't see this as an on-topic question? Perhaps they don't think it was researched sufficiently... it doesn't really matter.

Comment: It is researched sufficiently. I just found multiple opinions on the internet (some saying I would die, some saying it was  nutritious, etc)

Comment: If you don't tell us about your research, we can not know you did it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's perfectly safe.

Pet food has to go through the same sort of preservation methods as human food in order to give it a good shelf life so it's not going to have nasty foodborne illnesses. Cat and human metabolisms aren't too far off, and cats don't require nutrients which are harmful to humans so it won't hurt you one bit.

As for whether it would be healthy to eat long term that's a different story and not for this site.

Comment: Some documentation to support this: http://www.popsci.com/scitech/article/2009-02/can-people-safely-eat-cat-food-0 . I would note that there are some "fancy" cat foods that are sold raw... which is why I made the comment I did earlier asking if it needed to be refrigerated. :) While cats don't need food to be cooked, humans are more likely to need it.

Comment: "It's perfectly safe." Is it really? I'm pretty sure the food safety standards for animal feed are a lot less stringent than the standards for human food. That's why it usually says "not for human consumption" on the container.